# MYSQL Select Query Very Fast, but creating temporary table from this select is too slow

Tags: mysql

I have a table **imp_acc_act_itm** that contains around **36 Millions** records, and the following query runs very fast and returns **only 21 records** from this table in **less than 5ms**

```
SELECT SKU
  FROM imp_acc_act_itm AS ii
 WHERE exists
 (
   SELECT 1 
     FROM acc_opr_rule_skus AS rs
    WHERE rs.object IN (2006)
      AND ii.sku = rs.value 
 );
```

Now when trying to insert those record into another table, or creating a temporary table from it, it takes more than a minute to finish:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT SKU
  FROM imp_acc_act_itm AS ii
 WHERE exists
 (
   SELECT 1 
     FROM acc_opr_rule_skus AS rs
    WHERE rs.object IN (2006)
      AND ii.sku = rs.value 
 );
```

Anyone has an explanation for that?

Please note that I am using MariaDB-10.3.14 with InnoDB Engine.
And here is the Explain of the Select Query:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                      | key                      | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | rs    | ref  | PRIMARY,FK__acc_opr_rule_skus__object,FK__acc_opr_rule_skus__value | PRIMARY                  | 4       | const                |    1 | Using index |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | ii    | ref  | FK__imp_acc_act_itm__sku                                           | FK__imp_acc_act_itm__sku | 4       | eshop_fadel.rs.value |  238 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: You didn't tell us which version of MySQL you're running, or which database engine. I read that changing the database engine might help: `ENGINE=MyISAM`. They also often refer to memory problems. Having the output of an `EXPLAIN` might also help to discover what's going on.

Comment: If your final table is so compact then (1) specify table structure explicitly (2) add `ENGINE = Memory` to your table definition. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (SKU INT) ENGINE = Memory AS SELECT SKU ...`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, thank you for your comment, I am using MariaDB-10.3.14 with InnoDB Engine. I updated the question and added also the explain of the select query.
I will try with MyISAM engine and get back to you.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` for the select query looks good. Could you also add the `EXPLAIN` for the table creation query? It should be similar, but you never know.

Comment: This may also be useful: Those 5 ms are a bit quick. This is probably a cached query. So to test the real speed of a query you need to switch off caching with: [SQL_NO_CACHE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html). One explanation could be that the naked select query uses the cache and the one in the create table query not.

Comment: @Akina, thanks for your comment, I tried to create the temp table ENGINE=Memory with same result.
I also tried to insert into a normal InnoDB table.
I will retry to create a similar scenario on a fresh installation of latest version of MariaDB, to see if this will be solved.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I added SQL_NO_CACHE and got same result in less than 5 ms.
About the "EXPLAIN for the table creation", how can I do that? as far as I know, I can only Explain a Select Query not an Insert or Create

Comment: Sorry, yes, explain doesn't work table creations. That caching thing was worth a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see what makes it slow, but this might be a workaround:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (SKU ...);

INSERT INTO temp_table
    SELECT SKU
      FROM imp_acc_act_itm AS ii
     WHERE exists
     (
       SELECT 1 
         FROM acc_opr_rule_skus AS rs
        WHERE rs.object IN (2006)
          AND ii.sku = rs.value 
     );
```

Another thought is to turn the `SELECT` around:

```
SELECT rs.value AS SKU
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT value
               FROM acc_opr_rule_skus 
               WHERE rs.object IN (2006) ) AS rs
    JOIN imp_acc_act_itm AS ii ON ii.sku = rs.value
```

At that point these indexes may help a lot:

```
acc_opr_rule_skus: INDEX(object, value)
imp_acc_act_itm:  INDEX(SKU)   -- unless it is the `PRIMARY KEY`
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply.

The first workaround of the temporary table has same slow result.

The second workaround of using a JOIN instead of the EXISTS has much better result on the Insert which can fix the issue (but the old select using EXISTS had double speed of the JOIN).

I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269122/why-is-mysql-insert-into-select-so-much-slower-than-a-select-alone) with a workaround of SELECT INTO OUTFILE, then INSERT FROM INFILE which has a good performance.

I am just wondering why this is happening.

Comment: @ImaDaou - Thanks for the feedback.  I would be very surprised if the 2-step, via a file, OUTFILE+INFILE would be even in the running!

Comment: This whole issue is very weird. I don't know how, but yes the outfile is faster. if I had some time, I will try to prepare a "how to reproduce code".