# DB2 INSERT INTO … SELECT lock

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2, locking

There is an application Application1 which is issuing insert statement that we are using in Prod

```
    INSERT INTO Table1
    (SELECT FROM Table2
    WHERE conditions are true)
```

There is another application Apllication2 which is doing a select query on Table2

```
    SELECT FROM Table2
    WHERE conditions are true
    with ur
```

Now whenever the insert query is running, the second query is running very slow, sometimes getting read timed out.

I tried to find if the Table2 was getting locked due to being part of the insert statement, but I couldn't find any concrete evidence.

I did find something for MySQL
[How to improve INSERT INTO ... SELECT locking behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640898/how-to-improve-insert-into-select-locking-behavior)

but nothing for DB2.

Can somebody please help me understand the cause of slowness ?

Comment: Do you just want an explanation, or also a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The insert statement is almost certainly issuing locks against table2. However, if your second statement has `with UR` then it is likely it can avoid those locks. If you have a test system you can try setting the registry variable DB2_WORKLOAD to WAS (which sets all these: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0011218.html).

I suggest using `dsmtop` or `MONREPORT.DBSUMMARY` (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0056370.html) to determine where time is actually being spent for the read-only query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use second query as below:
SELECT FROM Table2 WITH(NOLOCK)
 WHERE conditions are true

Note: But It will give you dirty read.

Comment: Edited the question.The second query is run WITH UR.